# Moving Classic ASP between two IIS 6 machines with VB6 DLL

Tags: iis, asp-classic, iis-6

I have just started to debug a Classic ASP website. The old development environment was running in a VM machine on Windows Server 2003.

I have created a new Windows Server 2003 R2 server and have transferred the website.

The site also uses 11 ActiveX DLL's written in VB 6.

I have moved them over and used regsvr32 on all of the DLL's to register them and all appears well.

When I try and view the web page however I get the Error:

MX error '800a01ad'

ActiveX component can't create object.

/includes/somefile.asp, line 16

If I create a basic asp page, the page is served from both the root of the website and the virtual directory /includes fine.

Thanks

Comment: What is the architecture of the new machine `x86` or `x64`? If the DLLs are 32-bit you will need to register them using the 32-bit version of `regsvr32` so they are registered into the correct path in the registry. On `x64` machines this is under `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe` if you use the default `regsvr32` you will be registering the DLL into the 64 bit node in the registry. You might also need to set `Enable 32-bit Applications` to `True` in the advanced settings of your websites Application Pool.

Comment: I am using the 32bit version of Windows Server 2003 R2 as I thought it would cause less trouble when migrating. So I used the normal regsvr32 found in system32. All Dll's registered successfully

Comment: Are you able to create *any* COM objects? Try creating a `FileSystemObject` and see if that works. That will help us determine if it's an issue with one COM library or many.

Comment: Possibly access rights the `IWAM` account (if that is the identity your Application Pool is using) will need rights to execute the DLLs. If you're using `Network Service` it will already have the rights unless there is something screwy with your directory security.

Comment: Used: <% Dim q = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") %> and it worked ok. Just checked the DefaultAppPool identity and it is already set to Network Service. Oh, the directory is under wwwroot

Comment: Try creating an instance of one of your COM objects *outside* of ASP. Are you familiar with WSH?

Comment: Just ran VB6 SP6 created a new project and added a reference to the ActiveX DLL's ok. Intellisense is working on object in VB6.

Comment: A better test would be in WSH, though. It will do a "late-bound" instantiation (via IDispatch) in the same way ASP does. Or you could remove the reference to the library in VB6 and use `CreateObject()`.

Comment: I can create the object using CreateObject within VB6 OK

Comment: OK, Now I am really confused!!!!! I created a new page called test.asp and copied the code from the file I am having trouble with and it works ok. The permissions on the files are identical. The original file still does not work.

Comment: I did, they are identical

Comment: So we have two identical pages now? One that works and one that doesn't? And both are in the same folder and have the same permissions?

Comment: Right OK......Lets start again

Comment: Using two machines is a nightmare

Comment: So, if I add the dll as a reference within VB6 it works. If I try and use createobject it fails in VB6 with a runtime 429 Cann't create object. This is what is happening within IIS also. So this must be a registration thing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51753/discussion-between-user1546400-and-bond)

Answer (score 0):

Some other VB6 activeX dependencies were discovered. Registered them, now working sweet.